# Not allow user to click outside of messagebox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def showbox():
    messagebox.showinfo("title, random text")


def show():
    boxShow = Tk()
    boxShow.geometry("800x250")
    Button(boxShow, text="messagebox", command=showbox).pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
root.geometry("500x500")

show_button = Button(root, text="Show popup", command=show)
show_button.place(x=200, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

I know that when the `messagebox` is open the user cannot click the `Show popup` button that is located on the `root` window. How can I do it so when the `messagebox` is open the user is not able to click the `Show message box` that is located in the `boxShow` window?

Comment: You should change to `Toplevel()` instead of multiple instances of `Tk()`. If you want to make it so the user cannot click the button a second time then you could add a condition that controls the `state` of the button and disable it when you want to prevent them from clicking on it.